# Login system in .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, forms, authentication

I have a `login.jsp` page which contains a login form. Once logged in the user will be taken to `index.jsp` and this `index.jsp` should know which user is logged in. If the user refreshes the page he will stay logged in and not taken back to the `login.jsp`. So there need to be some sort of session.

**UPDATE**
Session Management

Comment: This is a very vague question. Look at some tutorials, try out some examples and let us know where you are stuck up. Hint: Try searching for "jsp servlets + session management + tutorials"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the session object:

```
<%
   String name = "testme";
   session.setAttribute( "theName", name ); //write as an attribute in the session object
%>
```

and some time later you can do:

```
<% String name= session.getAttribute("theName")%> // retireve the attribute from the session
```

check here for a simple introduction:
http://www.jsptut.com/Sessions.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Once the user has logged in you should add something to the session, such as the user name, to indicate the user is logged in.

You might then like to add a servlet filter that detects whether a request is coming from someone who is logged on by checking for a user name on the session. If the person is not logged on your filter can send the request to your login.jsp instead of the actual page they requested. Using a filter like this means you don't have to write any logon detection and redirecting in your JSP pages.

Finally you might want to provide a logout option which kills the session with `session.invalidate();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.getSession()` to begin a new session. There you can save(using `setAttribute` method) your own Java objects which will be there during the whole session.

Comment: err you shouldn't need that, do you? the session object is always made available as the variable with the name "session" in a JSP page -> so no need for request.getSession() you can address "session" directly