# Redirect to specific page after login

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security, jboss5.x

In Java EE security, if a user tries to access a secured resource, they are redirected to the login page. After successful login they are redirected to previously requested secure resource.

Is it possible to redirect the user to a specific page, in my case application entry page?

Something equivalent to Spring Security's `default-target-url` and `always-use-default-target`

Comment: yes Spring security provides this, you also mentioned that , so you need it without spring security ?

Comment: i currently can't use Spring Security, looking for something purely JEE.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888977/login-system-in-jsp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `Filter` just as the Spring Security authentication filters are created. The following Spring Security classes show how they did it.

- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java
- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java#AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java#DefaultRedirectStrategy